# VirtualBox and VLC complain about missing Qt software, but I have installed Qt packages already

Tags: virtualbox, vlc, qt, libraries

I tried installing `qt*`, `qt-sdk`, `qt5*` and `qt4*` but none of them will even try to do anything besides vomiting errors all over the system! I'm trying to use VLC and VirtualBox but VLC complains about:

```
[0000562c635bed38] skins2 interface error: no suitable dialogs provider found (hint: compile the qt4 plugin, and make sure it is loaded properly)
[0000562c635bed38] skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate qt4 dialogs provider
```

and then VLC drops to a totally useless shell

And VirtualBox throws

```
VirtualBox: supR3HardenedMainGetTrustedMain: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox.so",) failed: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

and won't even open

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

PS: I have all the deps for all the programs!

Comment: You don't need to install qt dev pkgs to use virtualbox or vlc and any needed runtime pkgs would have been installed as dependencies. Have you made other changes to your system that might be relevant?

Comment: it is installed like a hour ago

Answer (score 2):

On a working system:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox.so
virtualbox-qt: /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox.so
```

The missing file `/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox.so` is provided by the `virtualbox-qt` package.

Let's take a look at the reverse dependencies of that package:

```
$ apt rdepends virtualbox-qt
virtualbox-qt
Reverse Depends:
  Recommends: virtualbox (= x.x.x.x)
```

So if you installed `virtualbox` from the Ubuntu repositories, and if it installed properly, apt would also have installed `virtualbox-qt` automatically.

**If you installed VirtualBox from the Ubuntu repositories**, and do not recall any error messages, then uninstall `virtualbox`, then run `sudo apt autoremove`, then reinstall using `sudo apt install virtualbox`. Pay close attention to any error messages. Check that among the dependency packages installed should be `virtualbox-qt`.

**If you installed VirtualBox some other way**, then search the existing body of broken non-Ubuntu vbox install questions on AskUBuntu. Consider uninstalling your unsupported version and installing the Ubuntu way.